# MP3 Editor for Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, software-recommendation

What is a reliable MP3 editor where I can set singer / band album, name of the song, year aired,

Answer (score 1):

I use [EasyTag](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG).

> EasyTAG is a simple application for viewing and editing tags in audio
> files.
>
> It supports MP3, MP2, MP4/AAC, FLAC, Ogg Opus, Ogg Speex, Ogg Vorbis,
> MusePack, Monkey's Audio, and WavPack files.
>
> And works under Linux or Windows.

Comment: EasyTAG even supports adding album art to your audio files and the ability to search online. It is, by far, my preferred application to accomplish those tasks.